# Constrain generic struct to have distinct type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have this `struct OneOf<T1,T2>`. I want to make sure that `typeof(T1) != typeof(T2)`.

I know type constraints cannot be restrictive in this way. So I thought I can check it in the static constructor.

`static OneOf() => new[] {typeof(T1), typeof(T2)}.ThrowIfNotDistinctTypes();`

However it is very bad practice throwing from static constructors, so this is not really an option.

I then thought, I will cache the result and just throw from the constructor.

```
private static readonly Boolean _areDistinctTypes_;

static OneOf() => _areDistinctTypes_ = new[] {typeof(T1), typeof(T2)}.AreDistinctTypes();

public OneOf(...) {if(!_areDistinctTypes_) throw new NotDistinctTypesException(); ... }
```

However then I remembered this is a `struct`. So I cannot guarantee that the constructor will be run because someone could just do `default(OneOf<T1,T2>)`. Parameterless constructor is not allowed for structs...

I could check and throw on every usage e.g. when someone uses a getter, but that adds a large overhead and I would prefer to fail early. Am I out of luck here?

Comment: Maybe you can write a Roslyn code analyzer?  I have no idea how to do that, but at least it gives you a direction to look.

Comment: Would that be an acceptable use case for you to require T1 inheriting from one interface, let's say I1 and have T2 inheriting from I2? That way, you could automatically prevent T1 from being the same type as T2 by using the generic constraint...

Comment: @Kzrystof That's really just moving the problem, no?  The same problem exists: how would you keep the interfaces from being the same?

Comment: @Amy Like this: `struct OneOf<T1,T2> where T1 : IInterface1 where T2 : IInterface2 { }` ... But this solution makes sense only if you have some control over T1 and T2...

Comment: This might be an XY problem. What is `OneOf` supposed to represent/do? It sounds like a monad-like thing to me.

Comment: I do not have control of the types

Comment: @Sweeper That's exactly what it is. I am thinking, it is kind of acceptable to not throw exception on `default` because nothing will match on it anyway.